# How can I get header from Drupal via ReST/AJAX call

Tags: ajax, rest, drupal-7, playframework-2.0

I have a Drupal 7 site that integrates with a Play2 Java application such that the Play app is a sub app of my Drupal application. I am able to seamlessly route to the Play app from my Drupal menu. So, now that I have a menu that provides the proper links to both Play and Drupal pages, I want both to share that same menu, actually the header (includes menu) and footer (with its menu too) are what I want to be able to present on the Play side by either having the Play app call a ReST service in Drupal to fetch the header and footer and pass them to the Play template, or better yet, have the Play template via AJAX call the Drupal side and get the header and footer blocks to be painted on the Play page.

I have looked at Services, RestWs and RESTful modules but do not see how I might accomplish this with them.

I would think that somewhere, someone has had the need to get the header and footer section from a Drupal site so that they could maintain those things in one place even though they are serving different pages from different "tools".

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear so we can only shoot with the answers...

First thing is that probability that ready to use solution exists is almost nil. I don't know Drupal, but maybe there's is some extension/plugin which creates ie. Site Map for the google as XML file, so you can read this ie. with [Play's WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWS) and render menu on the Play side.

Other solution is that you can create Drupal's plugin which will expose these menus within ready-to-use HTML on separate paths so you can fetch them separately by WS API and display on Play

Finally you can use WS API to get main Drupal page  source code (or other where both menus are available) and than parse it i.e. with [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) library to cut only HTML parts for the menus.

In all cases you should cache gathered snippets on the Play side in case when Drupal is temporary unavailable to prevent Play page's  devastation

Comment: I will look into the JSOUP thing as that sounds promising. Basically, what I want is the HTML for the rendered header and footer, so that I can use them on the Play pages, allowing me to maintain those pieces in one place, Drupal. Your second option sounds like it might work also if I understand what you are suggesting. My research was leading me towards a couple of page templates, one returning only header html snippet and the other only footer html snippet.

Comment: Yup if you can prepare header-only and footer-only templates and show them on separate URLs it will be easiest to fetch with WS API - no further parsing required